# Install "windows 8" version of DISM on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-installer

Is there a simple way of installing the Windows 8 version of [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj980032(v=winembedded.81).aspx) tool on Windows 7?

Windows 7 does have a version of `DISM` installed, but with much less functionality, in particular it lacks the following commands

```
dism /Delete-Image
dism /Split-Image
dism /Export-Image
```

**(failed) try:** 
I tried a naive way (below) of copy-paste. It doesn't work. When I call the windows 8 binary, it fails with a message box "missing `api-ms-win-downlevel-kernel32-l1-1-0.dll`" (is that a *real* DLL, by the way?

- Copy the binaries from windows 8 `%SYSTEM%` and `%SYSTEM%\Dism`
- Paste them to win7 `%SYSTEM%` and `%SYSTEM%\Dism`
- Register each dll with an elevated `regsvr32.exe`. Some succeed, some fail

Comment: install the Windows 8.1 ADK: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39982

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per default a Windows 7 installation comes with DISM 6.1.7600.16385.

What you can do here is to upgrade it to DISM 6.3.9600.17029 which will support:

```
dism /Delete-Image
dism /Split-Image
dism /Export-Image
```

All you need to do is:

1. Download and install the **Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK) for Windows 8.1 Update** from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-assessment-deployment-kit) or the [direct download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39982).
2. When asked what features to install, select only the **Deployment Tools** (54 MB).

However after that the DISM 6.1.7600.16385 is still presence on your Windows 7 OS.

To use DISM 6.3.9600.17029 you NEED to run that directly from:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\x86\DISM`.
Otherwise you will still have the older DISM version [as explained here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/401-add-windows-updates-to-a-windows-7-sp1-image.html).